# After normalization i get NA , NAN and 1e+00 type values

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 5000 rows and 785 columns. Data sets consists of integers from 0-255 what i want is to normalize min max [0,1] range excluding first column. So for that i did Following code. 
The result of summary(MNIST) gives me

```
summary(MNIST[c("X14","X234", "X643", "X543", "X666")])
X14         X234             X643               X543             X666       
Min.   :0   Min.   :  0.00   Min.   :  0.0000   Min.   :  0.00   Min.   :  0.00  
1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:  0.00   1st Qu.:  0.0000   1st Qu.:  0.00   1st Qu.:  0.00  
Median :0   Median :  0.00   Median :  0.0000   Median :  0.00   Median :  0.00  
Mean   :0   Mean   : 73.45   Mean   :  0.0298   Mean   : 79.43   Mean   :  3.49  
3rd Qu.:0   3rd Qu.:169.00   3rd Qu.:  0.0000   3rd Qu.:199.00   3rd Qu.:  0.00  
Max.   :0   Max.   :255.00   Max.   :149.0000   Max.   :255.00   Max.   :255.00  

normalize <- function(x) { // even tried with function(x,na.rm = TRUE) {
return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}  

MNIST_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(MNIST[2:785], normalize)) //MNIST is orignal dataset and MNIST_n is normalised
```

The result of summary(MNIST_n) gives me after normalization

```
summary(MNIST_n[c("X14","X234", "X643", "X543", "X666")])
 X14            X234             X643            X543             X666        
 Min.   : NA    Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0e+00   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.00000  
1st Qu.: NA    1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0e+00   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.00000  
Median : NA    Median :0.0000   Median :0e+00   Median :0.0000   Median :0.00000  
Mean   :NaN    Mean   :0.2880   Mean   :2e-04   Mean   :0.3115   Mean   :0.01369  
3rd Qu.: NA    3rd Qu.:0.6627   3rd Qu.:0e+00   3rd Qu.:0.7804   3rd Qu.:0.00000  
Max.   : NA    Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1e+00   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.00000  
NA's   :5000
```

How can i get rid of NA and NAN and values like 0e+00
I notice that it only comes whn min and max have 0 values

Comment: it will happen anytime `min(x) == max(x)` cause 'normalize ' function is dividing by zero as result you are getting NA's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you cannot normalize a constant column to have values in [0,1]. What you can add to your function is the following:

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
 z=x
 if(min(x)<max(x)){ 
  z=(x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
 }
 return(z)
}
```

So you first check if the observation is constant and if not you do the transformation. Constant observations are returned unchanged.
A more elegant way of doing this is using the ifelse command:

```
 normalize <- function(x) {
   return(ifelse(min(x)<max(x),(x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)),x))
 }
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to return a certain constant (e.g. 0.5) in case the observation is constant, you can use the following code.

```
 normalize <- function(x,const=mean(x)) {
   return(ifelse(min(x)<max(x),(x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)),const))
 }
```

In the above example, the input const is optional and can be ommitted.

Comment: Good answer. However, the purpose of normalization is bringing various columns into the same range, so perhaps it is better to return a fixed value like 0.5 rather than the original one.

Comment: @mpjdem I have to disagree with that last advice. Normalizing constants makes no sense, and reporting an arbitrary answer is unlikely to be useful and likely to be misleading. OTOH, I would be interested in a genuine rationale.

Comment: It is true that it makes no mathematical sense. But depending on the application (for instance, plotting all variables on the same graph for visual inspection) it might be undesirable to have one variable far outside the range of all others. If NA and NaN are not acceptable, there are no 'right' solutions to normalize the data and it will have to depend on the application, IMO.

Comment: @mpjdem OK. For graphing, I'd just report which variables were constant if it was important at all. It would be a waste of space to plot 0.5 in one column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `na.rm = TRUE` in every function call to `min()` and `max()`.

```
normalize <- function(x) {
  if(min(x, na.rm=TRUE)!=max(x, na.rm=TRUE)) {
    res <- ((x - min(x, na.rm=TRUE)) / (max(x, na.rm=TRUE) - min(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
  } else {
    res <- 0.5
  }
  res
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I was distracted by your putting the na.rm argument in the normalize function call rather than the min and max calls. The other answers point to your probable actual issue here. I will insert it in mine too so no googler copies incomplete code.

Comment: after updating i get these values "0e+00 " and also in coulmn 1 i get 0.5 instead of 0

Comment: 0+e00 values are not a problem, it just means 0. The notation is because one of the summary statistics, the mean, is too small to fit nicely in the table in the normal notation of 0.0002.

The 0.5 value is normal, since it is indeed what I inserted when there is no right solution to the normalization, since NA or NaN is not acceptable to you. You might insert anything else, or the original value, or whatever would be good for your application. If all values in a vector are 0, what would you like them to be so that their range extends from 0 to 1? There is no correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

this will do trick i believe:

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
   minx = min(x)
   maxx = max(x)
   if(minx == maxx) {
       return(x)
   } else {
       return( (x - minx) / (maxx - minx) )
   }

}
```

Comment: still NA's on X14?

Comment: it didnt even normalized any cloumn